# How should I store User info for different sign up methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I am building a web app using ASP.NET MVC. I have begun by utilizing the Aspnet membership tables in in my db and using the out of the box membership proviers.

In addition to my membership tables I have defined a Users table with a foreign key back to the aspnet tables to store my apps user data.

Now I am at the point where I would like to implement a method to allow users to sign up with their facebook account.

What is the best way to store the data for users who sign up in this method? Should I create a seperate set of tables that more or less mirrors the aspnet membership tables for the purpose of storing the facebook access token and what not? or should I just place this info straight into my custom Users table and leave the aspnet tables unused for users that sign up via facebook?

One thing to keep in mind...I have also been using the aspnet roles tables and providers as well and would like to keep the roles aspect for users regardless of which sign up method they use.

Comment: If you're going to add support for Facebook login, you should probably consider making the mechanism general enough that it can be easily extended to other login methods that you may want to add in the future.

Comment: Simple.  Create a user profile to the facebook account into of the ASP.NET Provider username.  You did design your application in this way right?

Comment: @Ramhound So you mean use info taken from the facebook login to create the account using the asp.net providers?

Comment: @Ramhound What value would I use for the password?